# Spring Security authenticate logic

Tags: spring, spring-security

Endpoint security in Spring security is achieved with a list of filters. I need one clarification.

Suppose a filter has successfully authenticated a request and set the the authentication object in the security context. That filter also has called filterchain.dofilter(). Assume that the authentication.isAuthenticated() returns true - the filter has already set it.

If the authentication object in the security context returns true if isAuthenticated() is called, will the subsequent filters ignore authentication process (means they won't call authenticationmanager.authenticate())? Or will they still call authenticationmanager.authenticate () even if the isAuthenticated() returns true on the authentication object retrieved from the security context? Assume that the request path matches with the filter configuration (that means subsequent filters also will see the request as the request servlet path matches their configuration)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer as detailed as possible.

First of all, it's true that Spring Security uses a filter chain, but usually, the authentication starts from one of the filters in the chain. If you authenticate your users in multiple ways, then you need to implement multiple authentication providers (AuthenticationProvider). Take a look at figure 1. The authentication starts from the filter level and the responsibility is taken by a manager, named AuthenticationManager. The manager finds an AuthenticationProvider that fits. [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFle3.png)

In certain cases, you might want to implement multiple authentication filters. Say you have a custom multi-factor authentication (MFA) solution. But it is you who decides which filters are skipped. By default, the request follows each filter in the chain.

You can design a filter to be skipped if you implement the OncePerRequestFilter and override the shouldNotFilter() method to tell the filter when it doesn't apply.

In conclusion:

- to implement authentication in multiple ways you use authentication providers
- the subsequent filters will see the request unless you explicitly make them skip it
- I do also recommend you the first part of the book I wrote on Spring Security - Spring Security in Action. You'll find a more detailed description on how authentication, authorization and the filter chain works.

Comment: Thanks Laurentiu for the detailed answer. Usually we have only one single AuthenticationManager in the Spring context and it is that manager all filters will use. If one of the previous filters have already authenticated the request and set the fully authenticated Authentication in the context, will subsequent filter again try to authenticate as per the default manager logic (ProviderManager)? I understand that we can skip paths by using shouldNotFilter method, but let's say I intentionally make it pass through the other filters. Will it hit the resource (Controller class)? I am asking about t

Comment: Will it hit the resource (Controller class)? I am asking about the default AuthenticationManager logic (ProviderManager).

Comment: Many thanks to your vides. That's how I can discuss like this. Understood the internals very much!

Comment: Again, in general for authentication, you have one filter that delegates to the AuthenticationManager. In the filter chain, you have multiple filters, but they're not all authentication filters. You have filters for CSRF, CORS, authorization and so on. The filter chain looks like this: Filter A -> Authentication Filter -> CSRF -> Another FIlter -> Authorization Filter -> Another Filter -> ... -> Controller

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the fact you imagine you have multiple authentication filters all delegating to the authentication manager. But that's not the case. You have one filter that does that, at least in case you don't implement your custom filters which are your responsibility what you want them to do.

Comment: Thank you, understood it now. Great explanation!